# How can an MSIE proprietary filter be rounded?

Tags: css

I am trying to reproduce a radial gradient in IE with a background color on an element and radial opacity and another color an child element.But the element is rounded, and the semi transparent color goes out of the roundness.The rounding  is realized with pie.css, so it's vml that rounds the stuff.Any ideas?

Comment: A working example would help.

Answer (score 1):

Use pure VML to create the rounded element as well as the gradient:

```
 <v:group>
   <v:rect style='width:120pt;height:80pt' fillcolor="red">
     <v:fill type="gradient" />
   </v:rect>
   <v:group>
    <v:rect style='width:120pt;height:80pt' fillcolor="red">
      <v:fill method="linear sigma" angle="-45" focus="100%" focusposition=".5,.5" focussize="0,0" type="gradientRadial" />
    </v:rect>
   </v:group>
 </vgroup>
```